# Extend Zedgraph to produce SVG

Tags: svg, zedgraph

Is there any charting component that produce SVG chart?
I had work with Zedgraph, any idea how to extend Zedgraph to produce SVG/xml output?

Answer (score 1):

ZedGraph by default does not  produce vector formats. Even files saved in EPS format (there is such option in ZG) are in fact "fake EPS" - EPS file without vector information and with raster preview.

But you can overcome it by drawing on [Metafile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.metafile.aspx) and then maybe you will be able to save it as SVG.